# Google sheet API multiple ranges parsing

Tags: java, arrays, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to play around with Google Spreadsheet API I just incorporated with my App. lets say I have this worksheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TfRWRh0l09cxZ4HqwYWhRiBK4Lll3Jvj0XHpO-KEK2E/edit#gid=0

and I want to parse both data ranges into 1 output table of: Name, Age, Hobby, Occupation, School, and Gender. How would I write the code to differentiate between data range 1 and 2?

Here is the code:

```
private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
    String spreadsheetId = "1TfRWRh0l09cxZ4HqwYWhRiBK4Lll3Jvj0XHpO-KEK2E";
    String range = "test!A3:D6,B10:C13";
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    ValueRange response = this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
            .get(spreadsheetId, range)
            .execute();
    List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
    if (values != null) {
        results.add("Name, Age, Hobby, Occupation, School, Gender");
        for (List row : values) {
            results.add(row.get(0) + ", " + row.get(1) + ", " + row.get(2) + ", " + row.get(3)); //then i'm stuck//
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would move the data to 2 sheets/tabs.  Since you will most likely have 2 people with the same name, assign each a unique ID which is consistent between the two data sources.  Then use a portion of the code in [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) to read the data into Objects then parse it out to a third sheet.  To create the objects, you copy the portion under the Full Code which starts with:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The code below is reused from the 'Reading Spreadsheet data using JavaScript Objects'
// tutorial.
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

From there you will be calling the `getRowsData()` function to get the data from each of the two data sets.  Then merge the data based on a unique ID and populate the third sheet.  The problem with this, however, is you need some way to trigger it and you will be re-writing the data each time.

That said, this can all be done with 3 formulas in the third sheet and will stay up to date real time.  See cells A1, E1, and E2 on the Merged tab/sheet of [this copy of your spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OvzSLEyef0G7EwO8koQLPmPAZUdjWKxmaPODqUx2GWw/edit#gid=1397698434).

Here is the complete code you will use for the getRowsData() finction, copied from the site linked above:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The code below is reused from the 'Reading Spreadsheet data using JavaScript Objects'
// tutorial.
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// getRowsData iterates row by row in the input range and returns an array of objects.
// Each object contains all the data for a given row, indexed by its normalized column name.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
//   - range: the exact range of cells where the data is stored
//   - columnHeadersRowIndex: specifies the row number where the column names are stored.
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to the row immediately above range;
// Returns an Array of objects.
function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex) {
  columnHeadersRowIndex = columnHeadersRowIndex || range.getRowIndex() - 1;
  var numColumns = range.getEndColumn() - range.getColumn() + 1;
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(columnHeadersRowIndex, range.getColumn(), 1, numColumns);
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
  return getObjects(range.getValues(), normalizeHeaders(headers));
}

// For every row of data in data, generates an object that contains the data. Names of
// object fields are defined in keys.
// Arguments:
//   - data: JavaScript 2d array
//   - keys: Array of Strings that define the property names for the objects to create
function getObjects(data, keys) {
  var objects = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var object = {};
    var hasData = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
      var cellData = data[i][j];
      if (isCellEmpty(cellData)) {
        continue;
      }
      object[keys[j]] = cellData;
      hasData = true;
    }
    if (hasData) {
      objects.push(object);
    }
  }
  return objects;
}

// Returns an Array of normalized Strings.
// Arguments:
//   - headers: Array of Strings to normalize
function normalizeHeaders(headers) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
    var key = normalizeHeader(headers[i]);
    if (key.length > 0) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  }
  return keys;
}

// Normalizes a string, by removing all alphanumeric characters and using mixed case
// to separate words. The output will always start with a lower case letter.
// This function is designed to produce JavaScript object property names.
// Arguments:
//   - header: string to normalize
// Examples:
//   "First Name" -> "firstName"
//   "Market Cap (millions) -> "marketCapMillions
//   "1 number at the beginning is ignored" -> "numberAtTheBeginningIsIgnored"
function normalizeHeader(header) {
  var key = "";
  var upperCase = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i) {
    var letter = header[i];
    if (letter == " " && key.length > 0) {
      upperCase = true;
      continue;
    }
    if (!isAlnum(letter)) {
      continue;
    }
    if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)) {
      continue; // first character must be a letter
    }
    if (upperCase) {
      upperCase = false;
      key += letter.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      key += letter.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return key;
}

// Returns true if the cell where cellData was read from is empty.
// Arguments:
//   - cellData: string
function isCellEmpty(cellData) {
  return typeof(cellData) == "string" && cellData == "";
}

// Returns true if the character char is alphabetical, false otherwise.
function isAlnum(char) {
  return char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ||
    char >= 'a' && char <= 'z' ||
    isDigit(char);
}

// Returns true if the character char is a digit, false otherwise.
function isDigit(char) {
  return char >= '0' && char <= '9';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Karl_S this is awesome!